# Effect of a column of data on the final classification result

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I'am ML newbie but I decided to create a program in ML.NET for data classification.
However, my dataset has a very large number of columns, so I'll use another example.

There is an iris database with five columns:

- `sepalLength` (number)
- `sepalWidth` (number)
- `petalWidth` (number)
- `petalWidth` (number)
- `irisClass` (predicted -> Iris-setosa/Iris-versicolor/Iris-virginica)

Is it possible to investigate to what extent a given data column influences the classification of a flower to a given type of iris? For example, the value of the `sepalLength` column influences the result by 60%, while the value of the `petalWidth` column influences the result by 5%.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is either [permutation feature importance](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/explain-machine-learning-model-permutation-feature-importance-ml-net) or [feature contribution calculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.explainabilitycatalog.calculatefeaturecontribution?view=ml-dotnet)